# How to get Poetry install to ignore editable dependency configuration

Tags: monorepo, python-poetry

I have a python monorepo with many packages managed with [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/).

The packages reference each-other using editable dependencies, e.g:

```
poetry add --editable ./my-package/
```

In some narrow cases, like installing on docker, I want to be able to install those projects while ignoring the editable configuration, meaning all dependencies marked as editable will be installed fully, as if they weren't marked as editable.

Is there a way to get that behavior?

Could [Poetry plugins](https://python-poetry.org/docs/plugins/) be a way to achieve this? if so, what would that look like?

Comment: At some point there was a trick where you could list the same dependency once as normal dependency and a second time as an editable development dependency. I do not know if it is still works, if it is officially supported, or if there is a better solution nowadays. -- Anyway for Docker you might want to investigate better solutions, in principle you should not use Poetry at all in Docker images. I recommend building a wheelhouse in a first stage of a multi-stage Dockerfile. Or maybe use [*poetry-plugin-bundle*](https://pypi.org/project/poetry-plugin-bundle/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for today (version 1.7.1, not sure what version this was added in) the `poetry install` command supports a `--no-directory` flag that excludes directory packages.

From the command line `--help`:

> `--no-directory`    Do not install any directory path dependencies; useful to install dependencies without source code, e.g. for caching of Docker layers)